# In Star Wars: Imperial Assault can all rebels attack multiple times?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

I started my first game last night and my group is confused by one of the rules:

On Page 5 of Learn to Play Guide under Perform Actions #2 states: Attack a Hostile Figure. Only ***Heroes*** can use more then one action to attack.

The 'Assault' ability allows more then one attack. Does this mean that all of the heroes have assault? Does hero just refer to any rebel player or is it a specific type rebel player? I'm confused because one of the rebel characters has the assault ability so I need to know how it differs from the rule above.

Due to the use of the word 'assault' which is also in the title I have found this difficult to google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hero" is a very special term in this game.  Only the main characters that you start the game with are heroes. You can pick up other, non-hero characters as you play through the game. Example: han solo.  All imperial characters are also non-heroes.

Heroes can attack multiple times. Non-heroes cannot (unless another rule overrides this). That means that imperial characters and non-hero rebel characters cannot (normally) attack twice per turn.  You are right in that it's functionally almost as though they have the assault ability. However, they don't have assault on their cards, so they don't have the ability. Attacking twice is simply a feature of being a hero.

This distinction could potentially be important later. For example, imagine if a mission had a rule that the assault ability doesn't work during that mission. Or that no abilities work during that mission. In such cases, the heroes would still be able to attack twice, but other characters with assault would lose the benefit of assault

Comment: @atk can a Hero with the 'assault' ability attack more then twice?

Comment: @MichelleJS, I am unaware of any hero with an assault ability, so I believe your question is theoretical, only. I would venture to guess that either (a) such a hero can not exist because there are no rules to allow it, (b) it would be redundant and have no effect on the game since assault allows you to use the attack action twice, but does not grant an additional action, or (c) such assault ability on that hero would have different text, therefore being an entirely different ability with a confusingly similar name